# Blazor WASM - Global Catch 401 and navigate to login page on all HttpClient calls

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

In `blazor template httpclient` is added in the `Program.cs class`:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
```

and later used as following:

```
forecasts = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("WeatherForecast");
```

is there any way that I can override that base httpclient and inject it to all of my pages, that would:

- catch a 401 returned in any sever request (post/get etc.)
- try refreshing the token (call API for that)
- return to login when it fails to refresh

I saw that I could define a custom service that would wrap all of those HTTP client calls and perform the actions that I mention, however is there a way to do it in a better way?

Comment: Are you using WebAssembly Blazor   Standalone App ? Do you have an identity provider app or something else ?

Comment: the auth part is already working - i just want to handle a case where the token expired on front while doing the request (was valid when user entered a page)

Comment: i have an api that provides a jwt token.

Comment: Did you manage to capture 401 error, I am facing same problem.

Comment: @adopilot yes - just like Peter suggested i created my own httpclient that takes care of auth calls and checks for 401 to refresh the token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to intercept all calls via HttpClient then you'll need to create a service that lets you make HttpCalls, so you can intercept them in that and consume the HttpClient.

PS: You should change the registration from Transient to Scoped for any class (such as HttpClient) that implements IDisposable. That is going to change in a future Blazor template.

Answer (score 8):

1. Create custom `DelegatingHandler` with handling 401 response code.

```cs
public class CustomMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly string host;
    readonly NavigationManager _navigationManager;

    CustomMessageHandler(IWebAssemblyHostEnvironment webAssemblyHostEnvironment, navigationManager)
    {
        host = webAssemblyHostEnvironment.BaseAddress;
        _navigationManager = navigationManager;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CustomMessageHandler catch 401");

            // TODO: some logic (e.g. refreshing token)
            
            // Or just redirect to login page.
            string loingUrl = "http://some-site/login";
            _navigationManager.NavigateTo(loingUrl, forceLoad: true);
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

2. Register created **CustomMessageHandler** in **IServiceCollection** (in **blazor.Client** project)

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomMessageHandler>();
```

3. Also register configured httpClient (in blazor.Client project) with our CustomMessageHandler.
   `.AddHttpClient` requires `Microsoft.Extensions.Http` nuget package.

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("BlazorServerHttpClient", 
    client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
        .AddHttpMessageHandler<CustomMessageHandler>();
```

4. All httpClient's requests from blazor.Client to blazor.Server have to use IHttpClientFactory like this:

```cs
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class WeatherService
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

    public WeatherService(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        _clientFactory = clientFactory;
    }

    public async Task<WeatherForecast[]> GetWeatherForecast()
    {
        var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("BlazorServerHttpClient");
        WeatherForecast[] result = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("WeatherForecast");

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works fine except that momentarily before the browser is redirected Blazor presents the error bar and the console logs "Unhandled exception rendering component: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized)."

Comment: Is there a way without forceLoad: true ?

Answer (score 0):

The milkyWay answer is correct but it need **NotifyLogout()** for refreshing NavMenu items also because of a red line error in the browser and this error is the console browser : Unhandled exception rendering component: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized)

HttpStatusCodeService : DelegatingHandler class > SendAsync method :

```
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) // 401
await (_authenticationStateProvider as AuthStateProvider).Logout(forceLoad: true);
```

AuthStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider class :

```
public void NotifyAuthState()
{
    NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(GetAuthenticationStateAsync());
}

public void NotifyLogout()
{
    var authState = Task.FromResult(_authenticationState);
    NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(authState);
}

public async Task Logout(bool forceLoad = false)
{
    NotifyLogout();
    _navigationManager.NavigateTo("/Login", forceLoad: forceLoad);
    await _localStorageService.RemoveItem("token");
}
```

But I don't know how to logout without forceLoad: true. If we use forceLoad: false the red line error and console error appear on browser.