# Blazor WASM - Handle session expiry

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I am working on an application where login/security was implemented after the rest of the application. Unfortunately this means that all of the client-side services are already completely written and I would like to avoid needing to modify them all.

We have implemented a custom Jwt solution with a simple Jwt and Refresh token. Server-side, there are no issues. Client-side, however, runs into the issue of session expiry.

The client only checks if the user is logged in at one point - when the page loads. However, if the user leaves the page open until their session expires, the API will return "unauthorized" responses, as intended.

Unfortunately, the client-side doesn't handle this gracefully, as each service simply makes direct HTTP calls on an API client.

Is there any way to gracefully capture all unauthorized HTTP responses and redirect to login page in blazor?

Comment: this might be what you are looking for ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62693138/blazor-wasm-global-catch-401-and-navigate-to-login-page-on-all-httpclient-call

Comment: @jeb yep, that's perfect. I tried researching things like "intercept all unauthorized api calls blazor" and the like, but I guess I never got exactly the right words.